# how to add 4 image view to flipper in android?

Tags: android

i want to add 4 imageviews to flipper at a time.Please provide some sample code

my code is

```
    final ImageView imageview=new ImageView(this);
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);       

    final ImageView imageview1=new ImageView(this);
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);

    final ImageView imageview2=new ImageView(this);
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img3);

    final ImageView imageview3=new ImageView(this);
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img4);
```

I want to add these images to flipper on by one.

Answer (score 0):

You want each flipper to contain 4 imageviews?
Create a .xml layout with four imageviews, inflate the view, fetch your imageviews by findViewById and set their source-value then add the inflated view to your flipper with

```
myFlipper.addView(myInflatedView)
```